# it crashed when I start to build up the app with this error message. what does it mean?

Tags: ios, swift, crash

this is the error message:

> AppDelegate.swift:17:10: Objective-C method 'application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:' provided by method 'application(*:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'application(*:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)' in protocol 'UIApplicationDelegate'

Comment: i guess you removed override methods in AppDelegate class

Answer (score 1):

You removed the function `application(:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` from your AppDelegate. Create a new Project and look up the code in the new Project.